# Existence of solutions to elliptic PDE in undbounded domain

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Specifically, I have $Lu=f$, where $L$ is a linear elliptic pseudodifferential operator, on an unbounded domain of the form $\Omega\times [0,\infty)$, $\Omega$ has Lipschitz boundary, $u$ is 0 on all boundaries, i.e. $(\partial\Omega\times[0,\infty))$ $\cup$ $(\Omega\times\{0\})$. I imagine that there are existence theorems that contain this problem as a special case, but the results I have found deal with bounded domains.

Comment: There are existence theorems, but they require more information and conditions than you give. Any chance you want to say more about what you want or need?

Comment: This is the basic framework, but I want to leave the problem vague enough to accomodate any additional conditions that an existence theorem might require. I am flexible :)

Comment: Hi Max.  To get Deane's attention again you should ping him with @Deane.

By the way, which books have you looked through?  This seems very standard.  It should be in Hörmander ;).